# Returning a C# bitarray from Redis with StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to get back the bits previously set on a key using `db.StringSetBit()`

Currently I have the following:

```
byte[] bitLookup = db.StringGet(key);
BitArray barr = new BitArray(bitLookup);
```

My issue is that I cannot seem to figure out in which order the bits are returned as I get weird results with bits set in completely wrong offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out.

Iterate over the bits in the BitArray and if the bit is set calculate the bit position using the index of the set bit by using the following method:

```
private int keyFromBitIndex(int bitIdx)
{
    var upper = (((int)Math.Ceiling(bitIdx / 8d) * 8) - 1);
    var lower = (bitIdx - (int)(Math.Floor(bitIdx / 8d) * 8));
    return upper - lower;
}
```